# styled component computing style but not applying it

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, tsx

Dear genius StackOverflowians,

I am trying to write an app where users can configure questions and answers, along with defining help text for each question. I'm writing this in typescript React - which is handy when you want to define types of answers for questions.

I want to have a button next to the question that shows/hides a styled document. The button looks and works great, but the document that is hidden/shown doesn't get the generated style class that ought to be associated with it.

Here is the functional component to display the help document:

```
let HelpTextBody = function(props: { helpDocument: DocumentationStore }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.helpDocument.toReallySimple().map(tok => {
        return React.createElement(tok.tag, null, tok.content);
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`tok` comes from a custom class `DocumentationStore` that is pretty much a wrapper around `markdown-it`, a handy js library for working with md files, which I would like my users to write their helptext in (and store it that way).

So I do this (in a different module for DocumentationStore class):

```
toReallySimple(): MdJson[] {
  let bigParsed = this.md_.parse(this.Text, null).filter(
  t => return t.type == "inline" || t.type.indexOf("open") > 0
});
```

Later on, I style HelpTextBody with:

```
const StyledHelpDocument = styled(HelpTextBody)`
  background-color: lightslategray;
`;
```

Keeping it simple now so I can just see if it's working...

I then include it in a component with the button that I export:

```
class HelpText extends React.Component<helpProps, helpState> {
  constructor(props: helpProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hidden: true
    };
  }

  swapHidden() {
    this.setState({
      hidden: !this.state.hidden
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hidden) {
      return (
        <span>
          <StyledButton
            itemScope={this.state.hidden}
            onClick={() => this.swapHidden()}
          >
            Need Help?
          </StyledButton>
        </span>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <span>
          <StyledButton onClick={() => this.swapHidden()}>
            Hide Help
          </StyledButton>
          <StyledHelpDocument helpDocument={this.props.helpDocument} />
        </span>
      );
    }
  }
```

So I webpack it all and get stuff into the browser, and what I get back is this style tag (after clicking the button), which looks right:

```
<style data-styled-components="">
/* sc-component-id: sc-bdVaJa */
.sc-bdVaJa {} .gscXTZ{background:red;color:white;font-size:1em;margin:1em;padding:0.25em 1em;border:2px solid red;border-radius:3px;}.iwtdKP{background:white;color:red;font-size:1em;margin:1em;padding:0.25em 1em;border:2px solid red;border-radius:3px;}
/* sc-component-id: sc-bwzfXH */
.sc-bwzfXH {} .hAvMqj{background-color:lightslategray;}</style>
```

But my html for the document is missing the reference to the class (.hAvMqj I guess?)

```
<span>
  <button class="sc-bdVaJa iwtdKP">Hide Help</button>
  <div><p>Here the text is grey</p></div>
  <!-- ^This^ is the StyledHelpDocument... no class!-->
</span>
```

So where am I going wrong? I don't understand why it generates the style, and the component's HTML renders... but the class isn't applied to the component! What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your styled-components class isn't being applied because you're styling a custom component, but you haven't included className as a prop. Add className as an optional prop in the component you're styling, and also be sure to apply className somewhere in the render method for that component. For your case, it should be added like so:

```
let HelpTextBody = function(props: { helpDocument: DocumentationStore, className: string }) {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      {props.helpDocument.toReallySimple().map(tok => {
        return React.createElement(tok.tag, null, tok.content);
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This definitely was it! Works great now - thank you!

Comment: It's the only way to style a custom component?